# Conversion of csv to xslx and adding column using macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of about 400 files in CSV format I want to convert them into XLSX format. also I want to add a new column to the left while converting and want to add first 8 characters only of the file name to the newly added column. Suppose the file name is "`TZ125250 April 26 2015.csv`" it should add `TZ125250` to the first column until the last row where data exist in the spreadsheet and should save as "`TZ125250 April 26 2015.xlsx`", most CSV files have data around 200000 rows. the code I am using is

```
Sub CSVtoXls()

 Dim CSVfolder As String
 Dim XlsFolder As String
 Dim fname As String
 Dim wBook As Workbook

 CSVfolder = "C:\csvfolder\"
 XlsFolder = "C:\xlsFolder\"

 fname = Dir(CSVfolder & "*.csv")

 Do While fname <> ""
    Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(CSVfolder & fname, Format:=6, Delimiter:=",")

    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    wBook.SaveAs XlsFolder & Replace(fname, ".csv", ""), ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
    wBook.Close False
    fname = Dir
 Loop

End Sub
```

This code converts CSV to XLSX if I remove this section

```
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `ThisWorkbook.FileFormat` to `xlWorkbookDefault`

Comment: conversion of csv to xlsx is working ok if I remove the extra code, but I am looking for adding extra column and adding first 8 characters